# How to create a projection of private/protected properties with RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb, private-members

If I have an object with nothing but private properties such as

```
public class Foo
{
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private string Bar { get; set; }
    private string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

and store it in Raven, it will store those properties and everything works like magic.  If I want to do some sort of read-only query off of the collection, how would I go about doing so using an index?  (I'm actually open to any solution, even if it doesn't use indices.)

Obviously, something like this will not work because of the private access (and dynamic cannot be used in an expression tree):

```
public class Foo_LineItems : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Foo, FooLineItem>
{
    public Foo_LineItems ()
    {
        Map = foos => foos.Where (x => x.Baz == null)
                          .Select (x => new { x.Id, x.Bar });
    }
}
```

I'm sure I have overlooked something, but have been searching the web and cannot find anything that answers this specific question.  The obvious answer is to segregate the reads and writes, using CQRS, and not actually persist the raw domain object.  (This is just an experiment with Raven and CQS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have untyped API for doing this:

```
public class Foo_LineItems : AbstractIndexCreationTask
{
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
    {
        return new IndexDefinition
        {
            Map = @"
                    from foo in docs.Foos
                    where foo.Baz == null
                    select new { foo.Id, foo.Bar }
"
        };
    }
}
```